# Dynamically style certain tag in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

To style body you can simply do `document.body.style.color = "white"` for example, but if I want to do the same with `pre`-tag how do I do that?

Comment: Give your pre tag a class name or id then you can style that class or id using getElementById

Comment: So you can't change the actual tag style?

Comment: What are you actually trying to accomplish?

Comment: @epascarello change style of tag dynamically

Comment: Do you control the page css? Would make a lot more sense of a class on the body to alter things.

Comment: @Ferus something like this? `document.getElementById("pre").style.color = "red";` this will style #pre with color red.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best solution would be to alter the styles with a class. This is typically how themes work. You set a class on the body that alters the things you want changed.

```js
window.setTimeout( function () {
  document.body.classList.add("luckyGreen")
}, 4000)

window.setTimeout( function () {
  document.body.classList.remove("luckyGreen")
}, 8000)
```

```css
pre {
  background-color: #CCC;
}


body.luckyGreen {
  color:green;
}
body.luckyGreen pre {
  background-color: #CFC;
}
```

```html
<pre>
 Hello there
</pre>
X
<pre>
 Hello there
</pre>
Y
<pre>
 Hello there
</pre>
```

But for some reason you want to alter a class, you can write a new css rule.

```js
function addRule() {
  var styleEl = document.createElement('style');
  document.head.appendChild(styleEl);
  var styleSheet = styleEl.sheet;
  var ruleStr = "pre { background-color: red; }"
  styleSheet.insertRule(ruleStr, styleSheet.cssRules.length);
}


window.setTimeout(addRule, 4000)
```

```html
<pre>
 Hello there
</pre>
X
<pre>
 Hello there
</pre>
Y
<pre>
 Hello there
</pre>
```

Answer (score 1):

In this case you need to use `getElementsByTagName` as follows:

```
var tags = document.getElementsByTagName("pre");
for(var i = 0; i < tags.length; i++)
     tags[i].style.color = "white";
```

Comment: But if I create a new tag it won't get the style right?

Comment: Well yeah, but you can put this code in a function and call it when you do so, or explicitly color the new ones when created. If you want this property applied all the time, it is better to use CSS

Comment: but css cant be changed dynamically can it?

Comment: You can set a general property that applies to all the elements of this tag, even the new ones. But if you want specific behavior, the previous answer is the way to go.

Comment: How do I set a general property?

Comment: Something like this: ``pre{color:white}``

Comment: Thats css? Can I set that with javascript?

Comment: JS cannot be used for such behavior, where it can be only applied to the current DOM

Comment: And yes, that was ``CSS``

Comment: @epascarello can you give an example? Is it possible to write one statement that applies to all new elements?

Comment: Just for fun, it _is_ possible to dynamically create CSS rules using JavaScript, like so: `const style = document.createElement('style'); style.type = 'text/css'; style.appendChild(document.createTextNode('pre { color: white; }')); document.head.appendChild(style);` but it is definitely a **bad** idea. You should just write your CSS targeting all `<pre>` tags in a `<style>` tag or a separate `.css` file.

Answer (score 0):

You can create classes in your CSS then toggle them or add/remove them or manually do stuff like this.

```js
let v3 = document.getElementsByTagName("pre")[2];
v3.classList.add('three');

let pre = document.getElementsByTagName("pre")[0];
pre.classList.add('one');

let preAll = document.getElementsByTagName("pre");
preAll[3].classList.add('four');

let i;
for (i = 0; i < preAll.length -1; i++) {
  preAll[i].style.backgroundColor = "#ddddff";
}
```

```css
pre.one {
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
}

pre.two {
  color: blue;
  font-weight: 2;
}

pre.three {
  background-color: #ddffdd;
}

pre.four {
  color: green;
  background-color:#ffddff;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <pre>pretty pre</pre>
  <pre>pretty pre</pre>
  <pre>pretty pre</pre>
  <pre>pretty pre</pre>
</div>
```